# When sent the result store in variable to email all the result show in 1 line

Tags: powershell

When I see the result in powershell it's quite good but after sent to email all the result in $list is showing in 1 line. Any problem with my code?

```
$servers = "serveraddress"
$recipients = "anything@gmail.com" 

foreach ($server in $servers){
    Write-Output $server
    $list = Invoke-command -computer $server {$profiles = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path c:\TestFolder aaa.xml; 
    foreach ($p in $profiles){
        $p.fullname
    }
    }

}
$list
if ($list -ne $null){
    Send-MailMessage -From noreply@gmail.com -To $recipients -Subject "Something Wrong" -Body “Server: $($server)`nLocations:`n$list`n” -SmtpServer smtp.abc.com
}
else
{
    #do nothing
}
```

Currently the result will show like this, I want to make all the line below locations in new line.

```
Server: serveraddress
Locations:
c:\TestFolder\AAA\aaa.xml c:\TestFolder\bbb\aaa.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I suggest doing something like this:

```
$servers    = "serveraddress"
$recipients = "anything@gmail.com" 

$list = foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $files = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {(Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\TestFolder' -Filter 'aaa.xml' -File -Recurse).FullName}
    # next join everything with newlines to output a block of text that gets collected in array variable $list
    # DO NOT OUTPUT ANYTHING ELSE HERE
    if ($files) {
        "Server: $server{0}Locations:{0}{1}{0}" -f [Environment]::NewLine, ($files -join [Environment]::NewLine)
    }
}


if ($list) {
    # show on screen
    $list

    # create a hashtable with parameters for Send-MailMessage
    $mailParams = @{
        From       = 'noreply@gmail.com'
        To         = $recipients
        Subject    = 'Something Wrong'
        Body       = ($list -join [Environment]::NewLine)
        SmtpServer = 'smtp.abc.com'
    }
    # send the email
    Send-MailMessage @mailParams
}
else {
    #do nothing
}
```

Note I'm using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet. Doing so creates code that is easier to maintain.

Output would look like:

```
Server: server1
Locations:
c:\TestFolder\AAA\aaa.xml
c:\TestFolder\bbb\aaa.xml

Server: server2
Locations:
c:\TestFolder\CCC\aaa.xml
c:\TestFolder\DDD\aaa.xml
c:\TestFolder\EEE\aaa.xml
```

<sup>If you are setting the mail body to be HTML with switch `-BodyAsHtml`, then replace all occurrences of `[Environment]::NewLine` in the code with `'<br />'`</sup>

Comment: Seems like the path under locations all still show in one line in the email.

Comment: @ManChunLiew That depends. In your example code, you are not using the `-BodyAsHtml` switch. If in real life you do set the body to be HTML, replace all instances of `[Environment]::NewLine` with `<br />`

Comment: It shows like this now  c:\TestFolder\AAA\aaa.xml`nc:\TestFolder\bbb\aaa.xml

Comment: @ManChunLiew Sorry, I forgot to add brackets here: `Body = ($list -join [Environment]::NewLine)` I've already updated the answer.

Comment: hmmmm still show like this in email 
c:\TestFolder\AAA\aaa.xml<br />c:\TestFolder\bbb\aaa.xml

Comment: @ManChunLiew dit you add the `BodyAsHtml` switch? You can include it in the `$mailParams` hashtable like this `BodyAsHtml = $true`

Comment: Hmmmm, oh I forgot set it as true in $mailParams...Ya can works now..
But now how I detect if the there was no xml found it the server? So that it wont sent out the email? I try check if ($list -ne $null) but seems like have this in $list Server: server1<br />Locations:<br /><br />

Comment: @ManChunLiew Remove `Write-Output $server` that you may have left in. Do not output anything else in the loop. Also, use `if ($list)` instead of  `if ($list -ne $null)`

Comment: Not really can found where is the Write-Output $server. I'm looking on the code you provided above. I only want to sent the email when one of the server have the result.

By the way, I make your answer as correct first since already can show in seperate line.

Comment: @ManChunLiew I have added a test inside the loop. Now, if there are no files there will be no output.

Comment: I think all can works now!!! Thanks a lot. You help me a lots...
Because I need to keep track all server have problem or not this few days..